# jQuery simple .fadeIn demo not working for me

Tags: jquery, fadein

Why will this not work? I have been sitting here for hours as I am so confused... it works perfectly in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5SHdr/8/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#menu
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ddd;
}

#menu .link
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#menu .link.active
{
    color:blue;
}

#main
{
    padding:5px;
}

#main .content
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$('.link').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    var $visible = $('#main .content:visible');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if ($visible.length == 0) showContent(name);
    else $visible.fadeOut(500, function () {
        showContent(name);
    });
});

function showContent(name) {
    $('#main .' + name).fadeIn(500);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <div class="link" id="home">Home</div>
    <div class="link" id="blog">Blog</div>
    <div class="link" id="about">About</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="home content">This is the home content.</div>
    <div class="blog content">This is the blog content.</div>
    <div class="about content">This is the about content.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something really simple I am missing?

Comment: It just does not work. The div's are supposed to fade in when clicked but nothing happens.

Comment: did attach jquery file in html

Comment: have you tried changing the value? like from 500 to a higher or lower number?

Comment: try to put your jquery code within this and check $(document).ready(function() {}

Comment: It seems to work fine in the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is not inside dom ready, in fiddle in the left hand side panel second dropdown you have selected `onload` that means you script in the script panel will be executed on window load event.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.link').click(function () {
      console.log('x')
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
        var name = $(this).attr('id');
        var $visible = $('#main .content:visible');
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if ($visible.length == 0) showContent(name);
        else $visible.fadeOut(500, function () {
            showContent(name);
        });
    });
})
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LkBdfLJt1hVmYo9bmzrU?p=preview)

Comment: @Danny306 fiddle or the code? the code looks fine... but jsfiddle does not seems to be supporting IE8

Comment: The code does not respond to the click events in IE8. I tried `mouseDown` but that didn't help, I also changed the div's to text as I thought `.click` may not work with with them. It still does not work, and jsfiddle fails to load in it too.

Comment: I changed your code to this which works on IE8. What does the `consol.log()` bit do?
EDIT - I have posted the code as an answer. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code in your fiddle works. However you should place your event inside the $(document).ready function. Alternatively, you can move your script to the bottom of the page before the body closes

Answer (score 0):

I have updated this as the answer from @Arun-P-Johny above did not work with IE8.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.link').click(function(e){ 
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
        var name = $(this).attr('id');  
        var $visible = $('#main .content:visible');
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if ($visible.length == 0) showContent(name);
        else $visible.fadeOut(500, function () {
            showContent(name);
        });
    });
})
```